# How to find total combinations of following numbers?

Tags: javascript

I have the following Arrays:

```
[1,2,3]
[I,II]
[A,B,C]
```

I want to know how many combinations are possible. In example:

```
[1,I], [1,A], [2,I], [2,A], [3,I], [3,A], ...
```

There is something called the **Cartesian product** in Mathematics but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Why down vote without a comment?

Comment: You want to know how many, or you want to see the combinations?

Comment: I want to know, how many combinations are possible. I have asked a question like this for first time, because I am really not sure, if there is a build in function Javascript.

Comment: OK, so in your example the you always start with either 1, 2 or 3. Would the following be allowed : [I, A], [A, 1], [I, B]?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say, it can not be replaced like [A,1] and [1,A] and it can be [A,I] or [C,3]. Any possible combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the number of possible combinations of elements in your arrays using multiplicatation.

If you have 2 arrays `array1` and `array2` the number of possible combinations would be `array1.length * array2.length`.

```
var array1 = ['1','2', '3'];
var array2 = ['I', 'II'];

var posibleCombinations = (array1.length * array2.length);
```

The result of the above example is 6.

With three arrays you would calculate the possible combinations between each array and then add the sum of each.

```
var array1 = ['1','2', '3'];
var array2 = ['I', 'II'];
var array3 = ['A','B','C'];

var posibleCombinations = (array1.length * array2.length) + (array1.length * array3.length) + (array2.length * array3.length);
```

The result of the above example is 21.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [1,2,3],
    array2 = ['I','II'],
    array3 = ['A','B','C'];

var count = array1.length + array2.length + array3.length;
    count = count * (count -1);
console.log(count); // 56
```

The formula is:

```
n = total * (total -1) // -1 assuming that the first can't be equal to the second
```

Comment: @Vury Yes, if that's not what you want you should add some details to your question.

Comment: @Vury And it's on both ways. So count `[2,1]` and `[1,2]`.